# Recursion snippet: Please explain how the below code works

Tags: python, recursion

Here's a code that prints 16, but I don't understand how it works. Can you please explain?     My logic:
if n = 2, returned value = 2*(2+1) = 6

```
def fun(n):
    if(n == 4):
        return n
    else:
        return 2*fun(n+1)


print(fun(2))
```

Comment: See the comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430887/recursion-snippet-please-explain-how-the-below-code-works) for a demonstration on recursion

Comment: see what is you are getting on return call

Comment: fun(2) = 2 * fun(3) = 2 * (2 * fun(4)) = 2 * (2 * 4) = 16

Comment: @Sayse Absolute Legend!

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic example of recursion, i.e., a function repeatedly calling itself. The function gets called with 2 as a parameter. The function realises that the parameter is not 4 and hence reaches the `return 2*fun(n+1)` line. So it's supposed to return 2 * fun(3), for which it calls itself with 3 as parameter. 3 is still not 4, so we get to return `2*fun(n+1)` again and call it on 4. Now, on this function call, n == 4, so the third function call returns 4 to the second function call. That one returns 8 (2*4) to the first, and the first returns 16 (2*8). In other words, you're first building up a chain of recursive function calls which then wraps itself up in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You explained it in a simple and easy way!

Answer (score 0):

if n=2 the returned value will be 2 * 2 * 4=16
since you are reaching this line twince

```
return 2*fun(n+1)
```

this is there "2*2" is coming from

and when n:=4 you return n so you return 4

```
if(n == 4):
    return n
```

this is where * 4 is coming from

in conclusion 2 * 2 * 4=16

hope I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you passed 2 as an argument to the function fun(). As n or 2 is not equal to 4 (as per the if condition), we go to the else condition. So we get:

```
return 2 * fun(n + 1)
```

which is

```
return 2 * fun(2 + 1)
```

So you called the same function again, this is recursion.
Now again, 3 is passed as an argument to the function. 3 is not equal to 4, which takes us to the else condition and we call the function by

```
return 2 * fun(3 + 1)
```

fun(4) returns 4 itself. so we return to the above function and instead of

```
return 2 * fun(3 + 1)
```

we can replace it as

return 2 * 4 gives us 8, and the 8 returns to our first call.
Here, we get 2 * 8 = 16.

I have tried my best to explain it. Recursion is a confusing topic. If you still need more clarity, Please go through this [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_recursion.asp#:%7E:text=Python%20also%20accepts%20function%20recursion,data%20to%20reach%20a%20result.)